# In C#, is a dictionary whose keys are of type Type slower than a dictionary whose keys are of type ulong?

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary

I currently have the following:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, MyEventHandler> eventHandlers;
```

and an indefinite number of classes:

```
class MyClass1
{
    public const ulong MyKey = 0;
    ... 
}

class MyClass2
{
    public const ulong MyKey = 1;
    ... 
}
```

...etc...

My dictionary is to hold an event handler that corresponds to the type of class. Right now I'm using the `MyKey` member as the key to my dictionary, which works fine.

However, when other classes are developed now and in the future, I don't want to make the developer worry about having to have a key.

How much slower (if at all) is doing the following:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MyEventHandler> eventHandlers;
```

and then using the `typeof` operator to get the Type to index into my dictionary?

That way I never have to worry about a key.

I do care a lot about speed, because even though the dictionary likely wont have more than 100 entries, `typeof` will be called and the dictionary will be accessed thousands of times per second.

Comment: Set the bar 'how fast is fast enough', measure & benchmark (but be careful about the pitfalls), perform a statistical analysis, draw a conclusion. It's the only appropriate course of action here...

Comment: If it is for holding event handlers, why does the type matter? Why hold them in a dictionary at all?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with a plain old int? (i.e the resolution of `GetHashcode`)

Comment: why dont you just have a MyEventHandler property in each class?

Comment: Thousands of times per second is nothing. Only think about this once you reach several million lookups per second.

Comment: When you write that `typeof` "will be called" thousands of times, that is to be understood correctly. Remember that `typeof` is a ***compile-time*** construct. The C# compiler emits some IL code that represents this "constant" type. I don't know how much slower it is than placing an integer constant like `1ul` on the stack. You will have to measure.

Answer (score 3):

Types are represented and identified by metadata tokens, which I guess are 32-bit integers. The typeof operator makes a lookup in metadata tables to find the Type represented by the metadata token.

I believe that the JIT compiler will optimize metadata table accesses very well and therefore I don't think that you should notice any performance difference in reality. I would actually not be surprised if using Type as key would even prove to be slightly faster.

Since using Type as key would make the code much easier to maintain I would recommend that approach unless you can prove that the other approach is clearly more performant.

Answer (score 1):

If your dictionary is a singleton/multiton you can create a generic type to speed up indexation by this pattern :

```
static class MyHandler<T>
{
    static public MyEventHandler Value;
}
```

instead of

```
CurrentDictionary[typeof(Class1)]
```

you can do

```
MyHandler<Class1>.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how `GetHashCode()` is implemented. WHen the .Net framework code "finds" an object in a dictionary, it calls this method to perform the search. Obviously, in any Dictionary that uses a key based on a type where the implementation of `GetHashCode()` takes substantially longer than simply retrieving the value of a `long`, or a `uLong`, that dictionary will exhibit proportionally poorer performance.